# problem with camera preview in android

Tags: android, camera

I have the following problem:I have an app where I'm using the camera of the android device.
I have built my own camera.The `BIG problem` is that when the preview starts all the image looks resized.Every object looks longer, larger...

in `surfaceChanged()` method I've done this:

```
List<Size> previews = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```

I looped this `list` `previews` but I haven't found a better size for my preview.
The `list` `previews` has the size equal to 7 but nne of this items make my image look better!!

Here is how my method looks like:

```
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
            if (mPreviewRunning) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }

            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            List<Size> previews = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

            Size preview = previews.get(3);

    // the size of preview is 7 and looped each item....

         p.setPreviewSize(preview.width,preview.height);

         int f=p.getJpegQuality(); 
         Size   size = sizes.get(3);
         p.setJpegQuality(f);
         p.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);

           mCamera.setParameters(p);
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
        }
```

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [PreviewFrameLayout](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/PreviewFrameLayout.java;h=1ec629fd3f38d30306be308d040f937b09c24b4f;hb=HEAD) class from the default Camera app. It's used to display `SurfaceView` using the aspect ratio it must have.

Comment: But I don't know how to use that.Hellp me please:)

Comment: You can copy this class to your project and also copy a layout file: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/camera.xml;h=772106bfde89309d5137fa2cf4fa476d7991c176;hb=HEAD

Comment: Well, I did.Could u please tell me what next?:D .Come this way: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/810/hindi-language

Comment: That's how it's used: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/Camera.java;h=66b180517098aa8e41cc7e184058813462253127;hb=HEAD#l1761

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain your aspect ratio.

Try setting your preview size to 640x480 if your device supports it. This will maintain an aspect ratio of 4:3.

If your dev doesn't support 640x480 try setting it to a different resolution which maintains an aspect ratio of 4:3.

You can set the preview size on the camera like this -

```
 mCameraDevPara.setPreviewSize(PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT);
 mCameraDev.setParameters(mCameraDevPara);
```

Only after you set the preview size you can call the API `mCameraDev.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);` and `mCameraDev.startPreview();`

Comment: It supports 640X480 and actually this is what I set.The problem is that my activity is in landscape mode.The phone is in portrait orientation and the activity is in landscape...and the preview size was/is 640x480!!

Comment: what is your device resolution? the physical screen size

Comment: The resolution of the physical device is 854x480